# EAR deployment error on WAS 6.1

Tags: spring, websphere, web-applications

I have a webapplication on RAD 7.5 running on WAS 6.1 which builds fine. However on deployment on to the server it throws the following error:

```
    Error 404: SRVE0203E: Servlet [MyApplication]: com.mypackage.requestprocessing.servlet.impl.ServletFrontController was found, but is missing another required class. 

    SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server. 
    SRVE0187E: Check your classpath to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.
    SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime classpath
```

After this under SRVE0234I: Application classpath lots of files are listed.

It surely is a classpath issue. But I have not found a single place where exact solution on how to solve this issue is given.

Any inputs are welcome!!

Comment: Well, it provides one option, and it probably means exactly what it says--you're compiling with more classes available than when you're deploying.

Comment: On your project properties have you selected JRE Websphere 6.1 and Target runtime as Websphere 6.1? Keep in mind that WAS 6.1 is JDK1.5 and WAS 7 is JDK1.6

Answer (score 0):

Only one possible explanation: `com.mypackage.requestprocessing.servlet.impl.ServletFrontController` references a class that is available during compilation, but not available in runtime.

Wouldn't be surprised if your web project's Java Build Path (right click the project -> properties -> Java Build Path, look at the "Projects" and "Libraries" tabs) refers to projects/JARs that help you compile the project; however, the "Java Build Path" dialog only lists artifacts used for compilation, not for runtime. If you have projects/JARs that are needed for compilation **and** runtime, you should remove them from "Java Build Path" and add them to the "JavaEE Module Dependencies" panel (RAD 7.5) or "Deployment Assembly" (RAD 8.0), so the projects/JARs will be packaged into your `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: I don't know if that solved the OP's problem but I'm having this issue and I tried to move the JARs to JavaEE Module Dependencies, and it's still happening. Any other ideas?